# FOSUserBundle using own methods

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I am quite new at Symfony and actually I am trying to use my own method from my user.php in the template. it looks like this:

```
{% for image in app.user.getUserImage %}
...
```

But the only thing I get is:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined   
index: User
...
```

Up to now i thought that my user.php (my methods included) is extended to the FOSUserBundle so it can be used in the template.

Do I have to override the FOSUserBundle controller for that reason ?

@MDrollette:

from user.php:

```
 /**
 * Get userimage
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getUserimage()
{
    return $this->userimage;
}

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserImage", mappedBy="User")
 * @var ArrayCollection $userimage
 */
protected $userimage;
```

Comment: I think something else is going on here. It's not saying it can't find the method `getUserImage` it's giving a different error. Might need more information here to debug, can you post the contents of `getUserImage()`?

Comment: Please have a look at my edit

Answer (score 1):

You need to use app.user.userimage, as that's the property name. That will automatically call the getter for the property (getUserImage).

Answer (score 1):

`@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserImage", mappedBy="User")`

I think mappedBy refers to the name of the field in your UserImage entity and not to the User entity itself.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot. i figured out that i hat a typo. The variable $user in user.php should be $User.

Comment: And I think you want only the images of one specific user... "app.user.images" will fetch images of all users.